# Drop Down List (combobox) on Query Criteria - MS Access

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I'm trying to add a drop down list into a query criteria as follows

I created a form (name: Teste) with the combox box of months as the photo below shows
[image]

The combo box name is "Combinação0" with the code `[Formulários]![Teste]![Combinação0]`, I copied the name into the query (name: Gerar Boleto) criteria as below
[image]

Back to the form, I used the builder event (Open Query) as below, i linked to the "Gerar Boleto" Query and also inputted the edit option into the Data Mode.
[image]

However, when I run the event, selecting the month (April = Abril in Portuguese) the query returns without any register even having 3 register of payment on April
[image]

Follow the original payment register, highlighting the April payments
[image]

Therefore, I would like to know what is missing?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Setup looks correct but I never use dynamic parameterized queries. I use VBA to apply filter to form or report.

Comment: Yeah Id rather use VBA on the AfterUpdate event of the combo box to requery form

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake, on the original source for the combo box, there are 2 columns, (1st: ID & 2nd: Month) I was indicating the wrong column to be taken on bound column (It was considering the first instead of the 2nd one.

[image]